# PHP shell_exec can't execute specific command

Tags: php, shell, centos, scrapy, plesk

I am running a server on CentOS 7, managed by Plesk 17.

I am trying to run a command through `shell_exec` in a script but it fails everytime. At first I thought it was a permission/directory problem, but it's doesn't seem the case as the command runs perfectly fine from command line, with the same user that executes in `shell_exec`.

```
chdir("/var/www/vhosts/website.com/MyScraper");
$call = shell_exec("pwd & id -u -n & date & scrapy crawl crawler_name & date");
var_dump($call);
```

With that call, I see the correct path, then the current user (user1), the date date, then nothing. Meaning that the scrapy command doesn't work, and the last date call doesn't execute as well (it's how I knew the scrapy command crashed). Running only the scrapy cmd in the shell_exec obvisouly doesn't work as well.

How can I make it work? From putty, the exact same call, with the same user (user1) from the same directory, works.

Edit: I get this output from the call.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 128, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 46, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 19, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/version.py", line 6, in <module>
    import OpenSSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied
```

Comment: Probably a `PATH` issue. have a try using the absolute path to the `scrapy` utility or set the correct `PATH` environment variable for the http server process. Keep in mind that this process is _not_ the result of a login process as the one you are testing the manual execution with. That may easily result in a different `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I think it should be `&&`, not `&`. Doesn't a single `&` run the command in the background?

Comment: @aynber Even with only my scrapy call, it doesn't work.

Comment: @arkascha tried `/usr/bin/scrapy crawl mycrawler', works from putty, not from shell_exec.

Comment: Have you tried `shell_exec("scrapy crawl crawler_name 2>&1");` to check if there is output to the stderr?

Comment: @SamuelKirschner Good Idea, I have an error! But weird I don't have it on putty. I updated my question with the output.

Comment: It seems to be a SeLinux policy problem, it works if i do `setenforce 0`. Still trying to make it work.